# How do I solve $2^x + 3^x = 5$ type exponential equations?

Tags: exponential-function, transcendental-equations

I was trying to solve a variety of exponential equations and I came across such equations and I am unable to solve it by the regular "taking log" method, so how do I solve such equations? (Well I know we can use hit and trial method and it comes out to $1$). But is there any proper defined method/algorithm that is used to solve such equations?

Similar type equations:

- $2^x + 3^x + 5^x - 10 = 0$
- $2^{2x} - 4^x$

Comment: For $a^x+b^x=c$ where $a,b,c>0$ there is always a unique solution. You will need numerical methods(except when answer is immediately obvious) to solve these as it isn't possible to take log and separate the $x$ from the exponential. There is no general method, you will have to ask specific question.

Comment: Notice that $2^{2x}=(2^2)^x=4^x$ thus $2^{2x}-4^x=4^x-4^x=0$, for all $x$ (or, perhaps more appropriately, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 3):

Once you have identified an obvious solution, you can prove that there are no others by studying the sign of the derivative. Here $$f'(x)=\ln(2)2^x+\ln(3)3^x$$
is positive on $\Bbb R$, therefore there is only one solution, $x=1$ as you found.

---

When the solution is not obvious, there is in general no systematic way to find one. You have to study it case by case and possibly do a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 1):

In general - you don't. You use numerical methods.

Consider $2^x + 3^x = 6$, very close to your equation. It still has a solution, but there is likely no closed form for it.

Comment: It may have a solution but how can we say that it has no closed form solution?

Comment: When you say `closed form`, what does it mean?

Comment: @YatharthaJoshi As defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression .

Comment: @BAYMAX I changed my answer to say 'likely'. I don't have a concrete proof. For what it's worth, Wolfram Alpha can't find closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments and answers, most of the time, numerical methods would be required.

Let us consider the case of $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^x=b$$ with $0 < a_1 <a_2 <\cdots < a_n$ and write the equation as
$$a_n^x=b-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^x$$ Take logarithms
$$x \log(a_n)=\log\left(b-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^x \right)$$ which will make the problem much more linear.

To get an estimate, start at $x=0$ and use a Taylor expansion of the rhs. This would make
$$x \log(a_n)=\log(b-n-1)-\frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \log(a_i)}{b-n-1} x + O(x^2)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, this will give an (over)estimate which can be used as the $x_0$ in Newton method in fact $x_0$ is the result of the first iteration of Newton method starting at $0$).

Your case $2^x + 3^x + 5^x - 10 = 0$ being trivial $(x=1)$, let us try changing  $b=10$ to $b=100$. The estimate would be $x_0=2.81680$ and Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & x_k \\
 0 & 2.816800000 \\
 1 & 2.681921995 \\
 2 & 2.679370802 \\
 3 & 2.679370026
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Let us repeat with $b=1000$; the estimate is $x_0=4.28600$ and Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  k & x_k \\
 0 & 4.286000000 \\
 1 & 4.212332825 \\
 2 & 4.212049819 \\
 3 & 4.212049815
\end{array}
\right)$$  which is the solution for ten significant figures.